# Appointments on a calendar in wpf that don't visually overlap

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar, schedule, appointment

I have a schedule application which shows appointments at the correct times and spans for the right amounts. I'm using a Grid with RowDefinitions for every 15 minutes and ColumnDefinitions for days. The appointments are Borders with StackPanels inside that start at a certain time and use RowSpan to show the duration of the appointments.

How would I go about making a function that would that would properly adjust the Borders (mentioned above) to be properly hold more than 1 appointment at any given 15 minute interval?[I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq1nG.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50AVc.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the grid elments you can place a `Border` control

On a Border control You can do `BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"` to only have a bottom border shown as an example and any other combination.

You could probably use `DataTriggers` or `Converter` on the `BorderThickness` property

Also you could do a lot of this in Code Behind too, to get more granular access

I hope this helps

Comment: My entire app is based on code, not xaml. I can't figure out the algorithm to do the placement